# How to update the AWS EC2 hostname without reboot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, hostname

I know that to update the `hostname` of an AWS EC2 instance, I have to update `/etc/sysconfig/network` and then do a `reboot`.

But I need to do it without the reboot, is there a way to do this? I know that in some Linux distributions, you just need to `source` certain files to do this, but I cannot find what needs to be sourced in case of Amazon Linux.

Also, the updated hostname should be persistent, as in it should stay after restarts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also edit `/etc/hostname` to have the desired hostname, and then run

```
hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

to apply the hostname from that file to the system.

See `hostname --help` for more options.

Comment: There's no `/etc/hostname` file in Amazon Linux AMI. You need to create it manually. But still, your command ran successfully. Upvoted as well

Answer (score 0):

you can run `hostname foo.bar.com` then relogin and it'll be set to `foo.bar.com`